# Software Update wants to install printer driver update that removes support for my printer

Tags: software-update, printing, driver

I have a Brother MFC-9340CDW that I've had for some time. I recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Yosemite and found that among the broken things were that my printer no longer functioned due to missing drivers.

Following the link in the "Brother Printer Software Update 2.10" description, http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465, I found that that printer is unsupported.

So I dutifully went back to the Brother site, downloaded the software, and installed it. The printer now works perfectly for printing and scanning.

Shortly thereafter, Software Update tells me that my printer drivers are out of date. It wants to reinstall the driver that removes support for aka doesn't yet have support for my printer.

Right clicking on the update and choosing "Hide This Update" does nothing.

Normally this isn't a huge deal but it does mean that any time there are software updates I can't just "update everything," I have to expand the list and choose each update individually.

Is there any way I can tell Software Update, "you know what, I want you to assume that this is the version that I have, ok?"

Thanks.